# Alternative to using String.Join in Linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to use the Entity Framework in my ASP MVC 3 site to bind a Linq query to a `GridView` datasource. However since I need to pull information from a secondary table for two of the fields I am getting the error

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

I would like to be able to do this without creating a dedicated view model. Is there an alternative to using `String.Join` inside a Linq query?

```
var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

//join a in db.BankListAgentId on b.ID equals a.BankID
var banks = from b in db.BankListMaster
    where b.Status.Equals("A")
    select new
    {
        BankName = b.BankName,
        EPURL = b.EPURL.Trim(),
        AssociatedTPMBD = b.AssociatedTPMBD,
        FixedStats = String.Join("|", from a in db.BankListAgentId
                                      where a.BankID == b.ID &&
                                      a.FixedOrVariable.Equals("F")
                                      select a.AgentId.ToString()),
        VariableStats = String.Join("|", from a in db.BankListAgentId
                                         where a.BankID == b.ID &&
                                         a.FixedOrVariable.Equals("V")
                                         select a.AgentId.ToString()),
        SpecialNotes = b.SpecialNotes,
    };

grid.DataSource = banks.ToList();
grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Not knowing your schemas/access pattern etc, does performance suffer greatly if you change the query to `var banks = (from b in db.BankListMaster
                    where b.Status.Equals("A") select b).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {...})` instead? Otherwise, you should be able to set FixedStats/VariableStats to the string collections and do a second select (after an `AsEnumerable()`) to join the strings.

Comment: Performance is not an issue, this is a relatively small app. I'm pretty new to this language though, could you illustrate? I copied the syntax from your comment up to the `new {...}` line, and then placed everything I had from the `select new` section in my post inside the `{...}` section. After replacing `b.` for `x.`, the program threw a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: This was the line of code singled out in the error page: `.Select(x => new`

Comment: Could EPURL in BankListMaster or AgentId or FixedOrVariable in BankListAgentId be null for any row?

Comment: EPRUL, AssociatedTPMBD and Special Notes could all be null. FixedOrVariable and AgentId cannot tho

Comment: Alright, you rock thank you! By getting rid of the `.Trim()` on EPURL this worked perfectly. If you want post your solution as an answer. Thanks!!!! (Been stuck on this for a while now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not overly worried about performance (since it has subqueries, it may generate n+1 queries to the database, and if the database rows are large, you may fetch un-necessary data), the simplest fix is to add an `AsEnumerable()` to do the String.Join on the web/application side;

```
var banks = (from b in db.BankListMaster 
             where b.Status.Equals("A") select b)
            .AsEnumerable() 
            .Select(x => new {...})
```

At the point of the call to `AsEnumerable()`, the rest of the Linq query will be done on the application side instead of the database side, so you're free to use any operators you need to get the job done. Of course, before that you'll want to filter the result as much as possible.